# how to convert pdf file into html and display them in iframe

Tags: php

I am working on content oriented website and using I frames to display pdf.when I am opening that page in the mobile browser it starts automatically starts downloading the pdf,how could I display pdf file using iframe in browser instead of downloading.

Now i am thinking to convert pdf's into HTML and pass HTML file as source in frame.

Suggest me some other alternative if I'm wrong and if I'm right then suggested me some pdf to HTML convertors,which can convert in bulk as I have very large number of files.

**EDIT:**thanks,it worked but can how can i stop it from being download,i'm thinking of disabling right click,will it work

Comment: Possible duplicate of : [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Comment: Would it be possible to convert the PDF to an image and display that inline instead?

Comment: @CallanHeard yes it is possible,but it only converts first page of pdf in image,suggest me some method to do this

Comment: How have you converted it?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to upload your PDF somewhere and just use its URL.
You can also use Google PDF viewer for this purpose.

For more information check this [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Comment: if i upload pdf somewhere and use it url in iframe,it automatically get download in android mobile browser

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can make this possible one of them would be use the following `<embed>` element with source link to your pdf file :

```
<embed src="http://example.com/yourfile.pdf" width="1000" height="500" type='application/pdf'>
```

Another one is you can use the javascript library also :

[pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js)

and one last i have in mind  is you can use google docs api url to view the : `docx`,`doc`,`xls`,`pdf`,`ppt` or any other document file online by using the method below:

> https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://example.com/yourfile.pdf

Comment: do i need to put https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://example.com/yourfile.pdf in iframe or embed

Comment: You can do both of the things , it will work , but if you use the google link , you can view the pdf without iframe or embed as well

Comment: can you type an example for google link,because in my local host google link is working fine but when i am making it live content does n't load

Comment: Is your pdf on live server?  Google needs the pdf's files to be online on some server , as it works perfectly normal for me

Comment: thanks,it worked but can how can i stop it from being download,i'm thinking of disabling right click,will it work